# Different Observable of a QM System

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, wavefunction, observables

Let's say we have a quantum mechanical system, which is characterized by several Operators, meaning we can observe several physical quantities when we experiment on it (i.e Energy, Spin, velocity etc).
Now, without taking into consideration or caring about which observable commute and which not, let's say we have a quantum state expressed as a linear combination of the basis states of one of the operators. And we know which that operator is. Now if we make a measurement, from the quantum mechanical postulates we know that the system after the measurement will be in an eigenstate of this Operator.(If until this point there is something wrong with my understanding, please point that out.)

My question is:

If, in relation to this Operator the system is in an eigenstate of it, what about in relation to another operator, is the system in an eigenstate of it or in a linear superposition of it's eigenstates.

What i am trying to ask is : If the system after the measurement is in an eigenstate of the arbitrary operator that we are currently investigating, is it also in an eigenstate for every other operator that characterizes the system, or it's in a linear combination of their eigenstates

Comment: It really depends you know. But in general, there's only a wavefunction collapse associated with the operator in question. Any discussion on the Stern-Gerlach experiment is an excellent example of this(I personally prefer Sakurai).

Comment: "every other operator that characterizes the system" -- can you clarify a bit as to what you mean by characterizing the system? Do you just mean an operator that can be defined for the given system? Or do you mean it is one of the operators that belongs to the same largest set of commuting operators that the measured operator belongs to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quantum state can be thought as a (projective) vector $\psi$ in an (infinite-dimensional) vector space $\mathcal{H}$. If $\beta= \{x^1, x^2,\dots\}$ is $\textbf{a}$ (possibly countably-infinite) basis of $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{O}: \mathcal{H}\to \mathcal{H}$ is an operator on this space, then it is enough to know the action of $\mathcal{O}$ on the basis $\beta$. That is, the vector $\mathcal{O}(\psi)$ is completely determined by this action. This is because if $\psi$ is represented in this basis:
$$ \psi = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \psi_j x^j,$$
then $\mathcal{O}(\psi)$ is given by
$$ \mathcal{O}(\psi) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \psi_j \mathcal{O}(x^j).$$
It is particularly useful if the elements of $\beta$ are eigenvectors of $\mathcal{O}$, since in this case $\mathcal{O}(x^j) = a^jx^j$ for complex numbers $a^j\in \mathbb{C}$, and the previous equation becomes
$$ \mathcal{O}(\psi) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \underbrace{\psi_j a^j}_{\in \mathbb{C}} x^j.$$ Notice that in general, $\psi$ is not an eigenstate of $\mathcal{O}$ unless $\psi$ lies entirely in an eigenspace of $\mathcal{O}$ (that is, $\psi^j = 0$ except for those whose $a^j$'s agree). By the spectral theorem, every observable $\mathcal{O}$ admits such a basis of eigenvectors (in fact, they are orthogonal, and can be orthonormalized). However, there is no guarantee that the bases produced by two different operators will agree.

Now your question is asking what happens if an eigenstate of an observable $\mathcal{O}$ is acted upon by a different observable $\mathcal{T}$. The answer is the latter of the two you supplied: the result will be a linear combination of the basis vectors generated by $\mathcal{O}$ (this is the most general case). In the case that $[\mathcal{T}, \mathcal{O}]=0$, it can be shown that $\mathcal{T}, \mathcal{O}$ can be simultaneously-diagonalized. In this case, an eigenvector of $\mathcal{O}$ will also be an eigenvector of $\mathcal{T}$, and we have the former of the two answers you mentioned: applying $\mathcal{T}$ will yield an eigenvector (of both $\mathcal{O}$ and $\mathcal{T}$).

Comment: It bears mentioning that the most general state is a mixed state, rather than a superposition. But this doesn't change the gist of the answer.

Comment: "In the case that $[\mathcal{T}, \mathcal{O}]=0$, it can be shown that $\mathcal{T}, \mathcal{O}$ can be simultaneously-diagonalized. In this case, an eigenvector of $\mathcal{O}$ will also be an eigenvector of $\mathcal{T}$ [...]" -- this is not true. An eigenvector of $\mathcal{O}$ can very well not be an eigenvector of $\mathcal{T}$ due to degeneracy.

Comment: @PhysicsTeacher Good point, my solution only addresses the pure states of $\mathcal{H}$.

Answer (score 1):

If any of the other observables commutes with the one you measured, a common eigenbasis exists and, therefore, the system will also be in an eigenstate of that operator.
But in the general case, the measured state will only be a linear combination of the eigenstates of each of the other operators.

Comment: So that means, that depending on the process of how and what we measure, we can only affect the system partially

Comment: What does it mean to "affect the system partially"?

Comment: the system change it's state only in relation to the operator that we are observing. For the rest of the Operators, it is as it wasn't experimented on the system

Comment: The state changed after the measurement, so the expression of the state as a linear combination of the eigenstates of some other operator also changed (and, consequently, the probabilities of obtaining the eigenvalue associated with each of them when measuring that observable are different than the original probabilities)

Comment: This is not perfectly accurate. If $A$ commutes with $B$ and you measure $A$ then the resultant state need not be an eigenstate of $B$ -- because the eigenspectrum of $A$ can be degenerate.